# Loading existing Sqlite database into memory for fast computation

Tags: database, perl, sqlite, matlab, in-memory

Does anyone knows how to load an existing database (Sqlite 3) into memory for fast computation in Perl, MATLAB or Java? Perl is preferred?

I am working on a project that needs intensive computation, and I want to keep the real database fixed. So I want to read the entire Sqlite3 database into memory and perform anything there in memory.

I know the basics of in-memory database connection, but seems like Perl can only create a new database using this way, rather than loading an existing one (which is the option I want to implement).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `&sqlite_backup_from_file` method in `DBD::SQLite`.  If the handle against which you invoke it is opened on the ':memory:' database , the external database is read into it.  A corresponding `&sqlite_backup_to_file` method allows you to write it back when you're done.  These functions are effectively just wrappers around the [C interface](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) for backups

Answer (score 2):

I don't think SQLite provides any way to automatically load a database into memory.  All you can do is create a new, empty database in memory.  That's not a Perl limitation.

You could open an in-memory database, create your tables, [attach](http://sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) to your on-disk database, [insert into memory.table select * from file.table](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) for each table in your schema, and then [detach](http://sqlite.org/lang_detach.html) from the on-disk database.

Comment: Thank you cjm! The answer is useful, as I was wondering is it only particular to Perl. Your answer seemingly solved my partial doubts.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this issue would be to keep your SQLite database on a RAMdrive instead.

- On Windows, I have used the following RAMDisk driver without problem in the past:

  http://members.fortunecity.com/ramdisk/RAMDisk/ramdriv.htm

  Not very user-friendly, but pretty solid with some nice features.
- In Linux, you may try something like:

  ```
  # mkdir /mnt/ramdisk
  # chmod 777 /mnt/ramdisk
  # mount -t tmpfs -o size=128M tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk/
  ```